# Styling native Shadow DOM elements

Tags: css, html, shadow-dom

I always believed that you were able to access and override the styling on Shadow DOM elements. I saw the article on html5rocks which defines what webkit specific selectors you can use: 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 10px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

However when I tried this is doesn't work as expected - it appears as though some of the sytle properties cannot be overridden. e.g. height and width
However it does seem that setting the webkit appearance does stop it looking like a button.

Is this true?

What I would like to do is style the range slider so that the handle and track can be a different colour.

Here is simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/dCKd3/ I can hide the button but when I set a background colour it pops back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-webkit-appearance` (or `-moz-appearance`) is thought to reset/update the browser-style for an element, e.g. to style a `div` like a `button` (see [w3c reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp), and this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dCKd3/4/)), or reset the style of a `select` (see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vNK3Q/1265/)). 
If you browse with an apple mobile device for example, you will see buttons are rounded by default. `-webkit-appearance:none;` will prevent that. (see also [here](http://trentwalton.com/2010/07/14/css-webkit-appearance/)). It seems it is not fully implemented on desktop browsers, yet.

I was able to achieve the effect you desire with (**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dCKd3/3/)**):

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px yellow;
}
```

However, this is a hacky solution. If you want fully customizable controlls I would recommend [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) which is also browser-indepentent and does not rely on experimental browser features.

---

**Edit:**

You can find a list of values for `-webkit-appearance` [here](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/webkit-styles.php).

The problem with your first attempt is, `input[type="range"]` has set `-webkit-appearance: slider-horizontal`. This inherits to the children, and you're not able to set the background. When you add `-webkit-appeareance: none;` also to the `input[type="range"]`, you can set the background color to what you want (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dCKd3/7/)). You just have to set the width and height of the slider-thumb, because you just removed the `slider-horizontal` appearance which did that for you.

The new css would be:

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
-webkit-appearance: none;
outline:solid 1px yellow;  

background:green;

/* we have to set that, because it's not inherited anymore */
width: 10px;
height: 20px;

}

input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* this is important */
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response - most of it is useful background information which is always nice however you didn't quite offer a perfect solution or was able to answer the question as to whether some styling properties cannot be overridden. However you did provide inspiration as to how this could be styled so I will happily give you the bounty!

Comment: I updated the answer, hope it answers your question more now :)

Comment: Ah! So have to set -webkit-appearance on the parent element to cancel the inheritance. That makes sence.
I had a lot of luck without doing that by using pseudo elements within the shadow DOM: http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/dCKd3/5/

Comment: This post (http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/implementing-iphone-slider-unlock-with-input-type-range) also describes how to make radical changes to the input[type="range"]. Notice he also used `-webkit-appearance: none;` for the input

Comment: Here is the final range slider using your more elegant method!

http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/dCKd3/8/

Comment: Well, the css looks now definetly more elegant, not hackish :)