# Fill lower part of range control cross-browser

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, slider, pseudo-element

For an example, check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brenna/f4uq9edL/light/) (not in IE, please).

*(You can see a description of the control at [this link](https://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html).)*

She uses -ms-fill-lower and -ms-fill-upper to control the color on either side of the thumb, like this:

```
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 5px;

  /*remove bg colour from the track, we'll use ms-fill-lower and ms-fill-upper instead */
background: transparent;

  /*leave room for the larger thumb to overflow with a transparent border */
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 6px 0;

  /*remove default tick marks*/
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #777;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: goldenrod;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #888;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

[image: The result (in IE)]
<sub>(source: [brennaobrien.com](http://brennaobrien.com/assets/blog/custom-slider-ie-updated.png))</sub>

However, as far as I can tell, the `... ::-ms- ...` pseudo-elements only work in IE.  In Chrome, the code above seems to have no effect.  In Chrome, I just end up with this:

[image: The result (in Chrome)]
<sub>(source: [brennaobrien.com](http://brennaobrien.com/assets/blog/custom-slider.png))</sub>

What can I do to achieve this effect cross-browser?

Thanks!

Comment: **It's possible that those pseudo-elements are NOT supported outside of IE.** So there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Thanks, @Paulie_D. My goal isn't necessarily to use -ms-fill-lower to achieve the effect.  It's just to get the job done.  Is there not a different element I could use instead?

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. If there was, it would probably require JS. Look at it this way - It is cross-browser, it's just that IE users get something more.  Users of other browsers will never know.

Comment: [Possible duplicate of this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316539/styling-native-shadow-dom-elements)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this effect using gradient, look here: http://codepen.io/ryanttb/pen/fHyEJ
For example:

```
input::-moz-range-track{
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,black 50%,grey 50%);
}
```

Of course you need js as well to change percentage values.

Comment: This solution doesn't work in Safari, and only some of them work in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else finding this - with HTML5 now standard background-size is a great option if you don't want the fading look of a gradient. I've built my ranges around the tutorial at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp.

So my solution was in css:

```
.slidecontainer {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 60%;
    position:relative;
    margin:5px 0;
    background:url('/images/cyan_back.png') no-repeat left top;
    background-size:0 14px;
    border-radius:7px;
}
```

Then with jquery:

`$('.slidecontainer').css('background-size',$(this).val()+'% 14px');`

I believe this is also a bit more cross browser friendly.